# Simplyfing code with a lot of ifs

Tags: c#, optimization, simplify

I have a method which based on the enum, and to be clear at start we have this situation:

```
public void MyMetohd(Somestatus status)
{
if(status == Somestatus.Enum1)
{
DoA();
DoB();
DoC();
DoD();
DoE();
}
if(status == Somestatus.Enum2)
{
DoA();
DoB();
DoC();
DoD();
}

if(status == Somestatus.Enum3)
{
DoA();
DoB();
DoC();
}

if(status == Somestatus.Enum4)
{
DoA();
DoB();
}

if(status == Somestatus.Enum5)
{
DoA();
}
}
```

How would you optimize this kind of code ( it isn't mine)?

Comment: Check if you can't refactor your code to use a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).
(Check [this](http://ootips.org/strategy-vs-case.html) as well).
You can combine it with a factory method or factory class.

Comment: Are you talking about a plain vanilla enum, or is it a flag?

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? What exactly are your performance bounds and what is limiting it at the moment?

Comment: I wonder why no one mentioned Duff's Device: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Answer (score 5):

You can use a comparison if you set the values of each member of the `enum`.

```
enum Somestatus : int
{
    Enum1 = 1,
    Enum2 = 2,
    ...
}
```

Then just use comparison to do your code.  Because you always do `DoA()`, start with that.

```
if(status <= Somestatus.Enum5)
    DoA();

if(status <= Somestatus.Enum4)
    DoB();

if(status <= Somestatus.Enum4)
    DoC();
...
```

Keep on going like that.  This way all your functions will be called when the value is `Enum1`.

Comment: Good example, I think you meant This way all your functions will be called when the value is Enum1 instead, as Enum1 is the only scenario when all 5 methods should be executed.

Comment: I think that such 'solution' is hard to read, and will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: ++ That's the way I would do it.

Answer (score 5):

By optimize I'll assume you mean "make DRYer".

You're going to have to strike a balance between code which is easy to read (which, what you have is, although slightly repetitive) and code which repeats as little as possible

Just typing this makes me feel dirty, but if what you want is DRY and fewer LOC, I think it would do what you want.

```
switch (status)
            {
                case Somestatus.Enum1:
                    DoE();
                    goto SomeStatus.Enum2;
                case Somestatus.Enum2:
                    DoD();
                    goto SomeStatus.Enum3;
                case Somestatus.Enum3:
                    DoC();
                    goto SomeStatus.Enum4;
                case Somestatus.Enum4:
                    DoB();
                    goto SomeStatus.Enum5;
                case Somestatus.Enum5:
                    DoA();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unknown Status");
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary keys on the enum value and with a list of [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) or [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to execute.

```
Dictionary<int,IList<Action>> actionsPerEnumValue;
```

Populate this dictionary with the enum values and the actions for each.

In your function get the list of functions per value and invoke each action.

```
foreach(var act in actionsPerEnumValue[status])
{
    act();
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371054/uses-of-action-delegate-in-c) SO answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance a `switch` statement would seem to be the best approach, but you've got a lot of repeated code even in that:

```
switch (status)
{
    case Somestatus.Enum1:
        DoA();
        DoB();
        DoC();
        DoD();
        DoE();
        break;
    case Somestatus.Enum2:
        DoA();
        DoB();
        DoC();
        DoD();
        break;
    ...
}
```

While this is better it's still not ideal as you have the calls to `DoA` etc repeated.

Comment: Except without breaking. (Wait, does C# allow case statements to fall through without break?)

Comment: If you omit the break; will it carry on to the other values of status?

Comment: @BoltClock - no you can't fall through in C#, you have to use `goto`.

Comment: @BoltClock - No, it doesn't :(

Comment: @ChrisF, @Oded: Oh, that blows :(

Comment: C# does allow you to fallthrough in switch statements.  Just verified :)

Comment: @Frederik - not if you have code inbetween the cases though - "Unlike C++, C# does not allow execution to continue from one switch section to the next." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @BoltClock: Not it does not, you must specify a jump statement.  The best you could do would be use a goto Somestatus.Enum2 (Where Enum2 is the next in line)

Answer (score 0):

when you are working on same condition and different value for that ,at that time better u use switch..case...
Use If..else when you want to test multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you could also  "invert" the logic if that makes it simpler (depends on the number of enums to cover vs. the number of different actions):

```
if(status == Somestatus.Enum1 || status == Somestatus.Enum2)
 DoA();

if(status == Somestatus.Enum1 || status == Somestatus.Enum4)
 DoB();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you should use [State Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

```
// ANOTHER WAY
public void MyMetohd(Somestatus status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
        case Somestatus.Enum1:
             do_("ABCDE");
             break;
        case Somestatus.Enum2:
             do_("ABCD");
             // and so on...
        }
}

public static void do_(string s)
{
    foreach(char ch in s)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A':
                 doA();
                 break;
            case 'B':
                 doB();
                 break;
            case 'C':
                 doC();
                 break;
            case 'D':
                 doD();
                 break;
            case 'E':
                 doE();
                 break               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first way doesn't compile, as mentioned previously, c# requires an explicit jump statement, and does not fall through.

Comment: @Brook: Thanks man! I will never forget this now :) +1

Comment: No problem, I thought the same thing at first too, along with a bunch of other people.  The other thing is that you're limited in what jump statements you can use (break or goto).  It would be nice if they'd let you use "continue" to explicitly fall through.

Comment: Hummm... anyways I think the best thing would be to use some design pattern as has suggested by @Frederik Gheysels.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pattern to solve this will be the best solution like the others have suggested. I wanted to offer yet another solution.

I highly recommend NOT doing this though.

```
public void MyMetohd(Somestatus status)
    DoA();
    if (status != SomeStatus.Enum5) {
        DoB();
        if (status != SomeStatus.Enum4) {
            DoC();
            if (status != SomeStatus.Enum3) {
                DoD();
                if (status != SomeStatus.Enum2) {
                    DoE();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd go for the solution of Brook myself, I would like to point out another elegant and short solution.

```
public void MyMethod(Somestatus status)
{
    foreach (Action toDo in new Action[] { DoA, DoB, DoC, DoD, DoE }.Take(5 - (int)status))
        toDo();
}
```

However, this assumes Somestatus is defined like this:

```
enum Somestatus
{
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3,
    Enum4,
    Enum5
}
```

I like this solution as an academic and because is very short, but it certainly does not have great readability or maintainability.